# IIF expression for Count for division

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to write an expression of Count Division based on price as shown in figure

[image: table]

I am doing group column on Division but how can I get exact no. of count in Count Division Column those having price in their division.

I wrote this expression for Count Division column **=count(fields!Price.Value)** but it's not working.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It is working fine for me. What are the values you are getting and what are you expecting it to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIF condition SSRS column grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579468/iif-condition-ssrs-column-grouping)

Comment: http://i42.tinypic.com/21d39fb.png    This is the result I am getting when I select Division1,2,3 from Parameter. Actually it should count only those price values that are in Division and not all regardless parameter. I hope I am able to explain it

Comment: What your report structure like in your report . if you use the matrix , As far as I know ,seems it is not possible to achieve your requirements via the built-in feature , you could try to use the custom code (vb) in report to do it.
You could get detailed information about how to use the list collection in vb code bind with the ssrs report item .
See: [SSRS - Pass Field Value List To Custom Function Assembly And Display Result](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/686e9b74-4922-4298-9543-24432d51fedb)

Comment: Seems a thread with  the same requirement in msdn , you could check this [DYNAMIC month/year HEADER and REPEAT value](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8fc790d-3979-473a-8c3a-228234857fb6)